# Shutdown for socketserver based Python 3 server hangs

Tags: python, python-3.x, gevent, socketserver

I am working on a "simple" server using a threaded SocketServer in Python 3.

I am going through a lot of trouble implementing **shutdown** for this. The code below I found on the internet and shutdown works initially but stops working after sending a few commands from the client via telnet. Some investigation tells me it hangs in threading._shutdown... threading._wait_for_tstate_lock but so far this does not ring a bell.

My research tells me that there are ~42 different solutions, frameworks, etc. on how to do this in different python versions. So far I could not find a working approach for python3. E.g. I love **telnetsrv**
 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/telnetsrv/0.4) for python 2.7 (it uses greenlets from gevent) but this one does not work for python 3. So if there is a more pythonic, std lib approach or something that works reliably I would love to hear about it!

My bet currently is with socketserver but I could not figure out yet how to deal with the hanging server. I removed all the log statements and most functionality so I can post this minimal server which exposes the issue:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socketserver
import threading

SERVER = None


def shutdown_cmd(request):
    global SERVER
    request.send(bytes('server shutdown requested\n', 'utf-8'))
    request.close()
    SERVER.shutdown()
    print('after shutdown!!')
    #SERVER.server_close()


class service(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            try:
                msg = str(self.request.recv(1024).strip(), 'utf-8')
                if msg == 'shutdown':
                    shutdown_cmd(msg, self.request)
                else:
                    self.request.send(bytes("You said '{}'\n".format(msg), "utf-8"))
            except Exception as e:
                pass


class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass


def run():
    global SERVER
    SERVER = ThreadedTCPServer(('', 1520), service)
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=SERVER.serve_forever)
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    input("Press enter to shutdown")
    SERVER.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

It would be great being able to stop the server from the handler, too (see shutdown_cmd)

Comment: please post a [mcve].

Comment: @georgexsh I added more code so you have a complete example that exposes the issue

Comment: @georgexsh I am using the solution I posted below and so far it works fine; shutdown with the socketserver based solution never worked for me

Comment: have you tried two solutions in my answer? what is the problem with it?

Comment: like I said in my comment above your solution does not fix the original issues from my question

Comment: wait I see no comment *above* my answer?  am I miss something here? I would like to know how it fails and improve it.

Comment: you asked https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and I added the complete code. You solution does not fix the issues. Why? This is a very good question. Basically looking for this answer is what this whole issue is about. Don't know how to be more explicit without reposting the whole question, sorry.

Comment: would you show the code how the solution in the answer get applied?

Comment: you see the information is not symmetry here, I havn't see your new code.

Comment: and I proposed two solutions, not one, I don't know which one gets applied by you.

Comment: hmm, this sounds overly complicated. I tried the solution you advertised as ideal solution. If it works on your side then why don't you post the complete working solution? like I said I am still looking for a working solution for the stated problem - not a different broken one. Besides I can not add my solution as a comment. But you could post a complete solution  as an answer.

Comment: I do not think your solution implements a shutdown command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried two solutions to implement a tcp server which runs on Python 3 on both Linux and Windows (I tried Windows 7):

- using socketserver (my question) - shutdown is not working
- using asyncio (posted an answer for that) - does not work on Windows

Both solutions have been based upon search results on the web. In the end I had to give up on the idea of finding a proven solution because I could not find one. Consequently I implemented my own solution (based on gevent). I post it here because I hope it will be helpful for others to avoid stuggeling the way I did.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from gevent.server import StreamServer
from gevent.pool import Pool


class EchoServer(StreamServer):

    def __init__(self, listener, handle=None, spawn='default'):
        StreamServer.__init__(self, listener, handle=handle, spawn=spawn)

    def handle(self, socket, address):
        print('New connection from %s:%s' % address[:2])
        socket.sendall(b'Welcome to the echo server! Type quit to exit.\r\n')

        # using a makefile because we want to use readline()
        rfileobj = socket.makefile(mode='rb')
        while True:
            line = rfileobj.readline()
            if not line:
                print("client disconnected")
                break
            if line.strip().lower() == b'quit':
                print("client quit")
                break
            if line.strip().lower() == b'shutdown':
                print("client initiated server shutdown")
                self.stop()
                break
            socket.sendall(line)
            print("echoed %r" % line.decode().strip())
        rfileobj.close()


srv = EchoServer(('', 1520), spawn=Pool(20))
srv.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 7):

`shutdown()` works as expected, the server has stopped accepting new connections, but python still waiting for alive threads to terminate.

By default, `socketserver.ThreadingMixIn` will create new threads to handle incoming connection and by default, those are non-daemon threads, so python will wait for all alive non-daemon threads to terminate.

Of course, you could make the server spawn daemon threads, then python will not waiting:

> The ThreadingMixIn class defines an attribute daemon_threads, which indicates whether or not the server should wait for thread termination. You should set the flag explicitly if you would like threads to behave autonomously; the default is False, meaning that Python will not exit until all threads created by ThreadingMixIn have exited.

```
class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    daemon_threads = True
```

But that is not the ideal solution, you should check why threads never terminate, usually, the server should stop processing connection when no new data available or client shutdown connection:

```
import socketserver
import threading


shutdown_evt = threading.Event()


class service(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.request.setblocking(False)
        while True:
            try:
                msg = self.request.recv(1024)
                if msg == b'shutdown':
                    shutdown_evt.set()
                    break
                elif msg:
                    self.request.send(b'you said: ' + msg)
                if shutdown_evt.wait(0.1):
                    break
            except Exception as e:
                break


class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass


def run():
    SERVER = ThreadedTCPServer(('127.0.0.1', 10000), service)
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=SERVER.serve_forever)
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    input("Press enter to shutdown")
    shutdown_evt.set()
    SERVER.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 0):

after more research I found a sample that works using **asyncio**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import asyncio

# after further research I found this relevant europython talk:
#     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pi49aiLBas8
# * protocols and transport are useful if you do not have tons of socket based code
# * event loop pushes data in
# * transport used to push data back to the client
# found decent sample in book by wrox "professional python"


class ServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        self.write('Welcome')

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        self.transport = None

    def data_received(self, data):
        if not data or data == '':
            return
        message = data.decode('ascii')
        command = message.strip().split(' ')[0].lower()
        args = message.strip().split(' ')[1:]

        #sanity check
        if not hasattr(self, 'command_%s' % command):
            self.write('Invalid command: %s' % command)
            return

        # run command
        try:
            return getattr(self, 'command_%s' % command)(*args)
        except Exception as ex:
            self.write('Error: %s' % str(ex))

    def write(self, msg):
        self.transport.write((msg + '\n').encode('ascii', 'ignore'))

    def command_shutdown(self):
        self.write('Okay. shutting down')
        raise KeyboardInterrupt

    def command_bye(self):
        self.write('bye then!')
        self.transport.close()
        self.transport = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = loop.create_server(ServerProtocol, '127.0.0.1', 8023)
    asyncio.async(coro)
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

I understand that this is the most useful way to do this kind of network programming. If necessary the performance could be improved using the same code with uvloop (https://magic.io/blog/uvloop-blazing-fast-python-networking/).

Comment: note: this works fine on linux but not on windows since on windows single characters are processed

Comment: for a working solution see my answer that is using gevent

Answer (score 0):

Another way to shut down the server is by creating a process/thread for the serve_forever call.

After server_forever is started, simply wait for a custom flag to trigger and use server_close on the server, and terminate the process.

```
streaming_server = StreamingServer(('', 8000), StreamingHandler)

FLAG_KEEP_ALIVE.value = True

process_serve_forever = Process(target=streaming_server.serve_forever)
process_serve_forever.start()

while FLAG_KEEP_ALIVE.value:
    pass

streaming_server.server_close()
process_serve_forever.terminate()
```